# Nested MATCH statements in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

`(client)-[:listens]->(album)-[:contains]->(song)` are my relationships. I need to find how many different and which songs are listened by clients have listened a song with ID 4 (f.e.).

In SQL I could easily accomplish that with double-nested `JOIN`s and `SELECT`s, but since I am a novice in `Cypher`, I'm kinda lost. The scenario is as follows:

1. Find which clients (their IDs) have listened to song with ID 4
2. Get all songs that have been listened to, from the clients found in the previous step, and return them (and their count as well).

I tried to start with smth like:

```
MATCH (c:Client)--(a:Album)--(s:Song)
WITH a, s, {cIDs: c.clientID} AS clientsIDs
// MATCH that gets all songs in albums listened by clients WHERE c.clientID IN clientsIDs -- how to make that?
WITH COUNT(s), COLLECT(s) as songs
WHERE s.songID = "4"
RETURN songs
```

This was another try:

```
MATCH (c:Client)--(a:Album)--(s:Song)
WHERE s.songID = "4"
WITH a, s, {cID: c.clientID} AS clientsIDs
MATCH (c {clientID: clientsIDs})-[:LISTENS]->(a)-[:CONTAINS]->(s)
WITH COUNT(s) AS songsCount, COLLECT(s) as songs
RETURN songs, songsCount
```

which obviously didn't work.

I just can't get around the part where I pass the `clientsIDs` to another `MATCH` statement...

Comment: is your songID property written as an int or a string? if it's not a string, those quote marks are going to result in 0 matches.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be overcomplicating things.  Here is my effort...

```
// find all of the clients that have listed to the song with id =4
MATCH (c:Client)--(a:Album)--(s:Song)
WHERE s.songID = "4"

// then with those clients find all of the songs they have listened to
WITH c 
MATCH (c)-[:LISTENS]->(a)-[:CONTAINS]->(s)
WITH COLLECT(s) as songs
RETURN songs, size(songs) as songsCount
```

Comment: That returns an empty list. As does my last suggested try.

Comment: do you have some representative sample data?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Milkncookiez You may want to verify that your types used are correct. Usually IDs are numeric, yet you're using a string value in your comparison. A quick sanity check of relationship types and directions might be good too. You may want to check that this returns values, and if not, fix it first and apply similar fixes in your real query: `MATCH (c:Client)--(a:Album)--(s:Song)
WHERE s.songID = "4" RETURN c, a, s LIMIT 5`